# Auto_Increment with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, auto-increment

I have a fragment of code in Java which inserts data into my database.

I was advised to put AUTO_INCREMENT and give each row a unique number.

But it now gives me an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column
>   'usersID' at row 1

I assume this is because it's casting the AUTO_INCREMENT value into a string?

How do I get around this as it's not my java program that creates the unique number, but the database itself.

```
pst.setString(1, "DEFAULT");

String query_to_update = "INSERT INTO `evidence_db`.`mcases` ("
                        + "`PID`,"
                        + "`Name`) "
                        + "VALUES (?,?);";
```

Comment: auto increment should be a number.

Comment: You shouldn't try to insert anything into this column.

Answer (score 1):

```
pst.setInt(1, 0);
```

Above was the line that I needed. Thanks to all that *tried* to be helpful.

Comment: This is still wrong, assuming that parameter 1 corresponds to your auto_increment field. For the auto increment to take effect you must not supply a value for it in the column list.

Comment: Hi @Perception. It seems to be working fine? If I don't define a value for it, errors occur.

Comment: You are getting errors because you included the auto_increment column in your insert list. Remove it and the database will take care of setting its value properly.

Comment: You did `String query_to_update = "INSERT INTO evidence_db.mcases (Name) VALUES (?)"; ... ; pst.setString(1, "<Name here>");` and you are getting the *exact same error*?

Comment: @AdamHinx Show us what exactly what you have updated in question. May be this could help to resolve issue.